# Hive Exists condition not working on multiple condition

Tags: sql, hive

I'm running the following query

```
select * from Data t1 
where not exists (select 1 from data2 t2 where
t1.diagonosiscode2 = t2.dx and 
t1.diagonosiscode3 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode4 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode5 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode6 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode7 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode8 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode9 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode10 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode11 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode12 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode13 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode14 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode15 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode16 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode17 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode18 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode19 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode20 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode21 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode22 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode23 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode24 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode25 = t2.dx )
```

the above query throws the following error.

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10250]: Line 2:33 Invalid
>   SubQuery expression 'dx': For Exists/Not Exists operator SubQuery must
>   be Correlated.

but the same query executes when I write for a single condition

```
select * from Data t1 
where not exists (select 1 from  Data2 t2
                  where t1.diagnosiscode3 = t2.dx)
```

whether hive supports only one exists condition.

I can't able to perform multiple in condition also since hive doesn't support.

How to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `left join`:

```
select t1.*
from Data t1 left join
     data2 t2 
     on t1.diagonosiscode2 = t2.dx and 
        t1.diagonosiscode3 = t2.dx and
        . . .
where t2.dx is null;
```

I notice you are comparing all the codes to `dx`.  So you could also do:

```
select t1.*
from Data t1 
where t1.diagonosiscode2 = t1.diagonosiscode3 and 
      t1.diagonosiscode2 = t1.diagonosiscode4 and
      . . .
     not exists (select 1
                 from data2 t2
                 where t1.diagonosiscode4 = t2.dx 
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this condition

```
where
t1.diagonosiscode2 = t2.dx and 
t1.diagonosiscode3 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode4 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode5 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode6 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode7 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode8 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode9 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode10 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode11 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode12 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode13 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode14 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode15 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode16 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode17 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode18 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode19 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode20 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode21 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode22 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode23 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode24 = t2.dx and
t1.diagonosiscode25 = t2.dx
```

can be transformed to this condition:

```
where
t1.diagonosiscode2 = t2.dx and 
t1.diagonosiscode3 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode4 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode5 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode6 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode7 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode8 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode9 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode10 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode11 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode12 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode13 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode14 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode15 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode16 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode17 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode18 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode19 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode20 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode21 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode22 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode23 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode24 = t1.diagonosiscode2 and
t1.diagonosiscode25 = t1.diagonosiscode2
```